# excel code not working in mvc to import excell sheets

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can't find any code to help me export excel style sheet into mvc. Is there anyone with a project or sample code that can show how to do this.

```
public class HomeController : Controller //home
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection) {
        if (Request != null) {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];  //file
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName)) {
                string fileName = file.FileName;   //filename
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                var usersList = new List<Users>();
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))   //stream
                {
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++) {
                        var user = new Users();
                        user.FirstName = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString();
                        user.LastName = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();
                        usersList.Add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return View("Index");  //return
    }
    public class Users {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }  //get set
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you search on SO?  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+import+excel

Answer (score 0):

// Review below code, you can take it and use it your way
u need to install nuget "ExcelPackage"

```
     public ActionResult UploadXls()
     {
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
            if (file != null && !file.FileName.Contains(".xl"))
            {
                TempData["description"] = "This file format is not supported, please use .xl or .xls formated file.";
                //ModelState.AddModelError("File", "This file format is not supported");
                return RedirectToAction("PropertyInventory", "PropertyBo", new { id = propertyId });
            }

            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                var PropertyIn = new List<InventoryModelView>();
                int idTemp = 0;
                var alreadyExistInventoryList = new List<InventoryModelView>();

                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                {
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                    {
                        var inv = new PropertyInventory();

                        inv.PropertyId = propertyId;
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            inv.UnitNo = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString();
                        }


                    }

                }                 


            }
        }

        TempData["description"] = "Great! Excel upload successfully";
        return RedirectToAction("abcd", "bcad", new { id = propertyId, flag = 1 });

    }
```

Comment: emailed u sir pls check

Comment: sir i'm waiting for ur reply @Saurin Vala